# Convert List of long to String set

Tags: java

Let's say that, for whatever reason, I have to convert a `List<Long>` to a `Set<String>`. To not loose any items from the list I have to create a unique `String` from the items. Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
public class StringUtils {
    private static final String FORMAT = "<%d>:%s";
    private static long counter = 0;

    public static synchronized String valueOf(long value) {
        return String.format(FORMAT, counter++, String.valueOf(value));
    }

    public static long getLong(String input) {
        int start = input.indexOf(":") + 1;
        int end = input.length();

        return Long.parseLong(input.substring(start, end));
    }
}

for(long item : list) {
   set.add(StringUtils.valueOf(item));
}
```

I think this is not a very elegant solution but at least it works. Can you may think of a better/faster way to do this? Btw. I'm limited to Java 7.

Comment: I'm not getting why you can't simply convert your `Long` to `String` without any interpolation

Comment: Because I would then loose items which are equal to each other in the list when inserting them into the set.

Comment: So why aren't you using `List` instead of `Set` ?

Comment: Due to API call I'm limited to `Set<String>`

Comment: Ok that's clear now, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access to the the `List` indexes, don't use an enhanced `for` but a classic `for` :

```
private static final String FORMAT = "<%d>:%s";

// ...

for(int i=0; i< list.size(); i++) {
   long item = list.get(i);
   set.add(String.format(FORMAT, i, String.valueOf(item)));
}
```

Note that your way to not lose duplicated elements in the Set is improvable : a String that contains two distinct information is not meaningful.
You could use a custom class that doesn't override `equals()/hashCode()`, in this way you don't lose any element :

```
Set<MyValue> set = ...;

for(long item : list) {
   set.add(new MyValue(item)));
}
```

Where `MyValue` is defined as :

```
public class MyValue{

  private long value; 

  public MyValue(long value){
    this.value = value;
  }

  public long getValue(){ 
     return value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of `ListIterator` which gives you the index.

```
    for (ListIterator<Long> iter = list.listIterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
        int  i = iter.nextIndex();
        long l = iter.next();
        set.add(String.format(FORMAT, i, String.valueOf(l)));
    }
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHNasMwEITP9lMsgYAMqaD/pXENuZQGnBaa3koP21hJlMpykGQ3oeTZ3ZWtQ6DpYcHaTzM7Xm2wwbNqK/Sm@Gplua2Mgw31eO2k4hNjcG/H8R/whHY9F@4EyaX9rz11wqCrzAnsvdqFQmthhlLDTxxtjWzQCbAOnVzAUmpUMHdG6hU8vrzOJm/wAIN0WGT3QzsYx6SoPxXdDIKmkgWUZMZ60fsHoFnZxHtHPk6aV3qVASj6Jqv@Xzlaz9h5PoIrqguqa6pLqpvQuw29uzwZkxdlT/sRGVjhgLy0@IawojRjiQ8XLSsD7HgNYb6kI0l8Cq6OMMk6xtdon8XO@XMfPpKapkgSdVwTnOpC7FgXJ1JkC@qYBkDhOBZF2AenQCU61u9yBHIUtssbVLV4WTKVJJ3w4OPP99aJkle14/Qy2inNyM/zQ3yI2/YX)

Comment: It will work but it doesn't look like the appropriate tool  if you don't need to traverse the list in either direction or to modify it during iteration.

Comment: `ListIterator` has nothing to do with wanting to modify the list. Thats like saying, there's no need to use `Iterator` if you don't utilize `.remove()`

Comment: It is not really what I would tell. I mean that you use a powerful API with some complexity that is not required here as you can perform it in a simpler way :  a iteration with `for` with `index`. It is like using a `Map` while a `Set` would be enough.

Comment: The implementation of [`ListIterator`](https://zgrepcode.com/java/openjdk/10.0.2/java.base/java/util/arraylist.java#L-944) is simple and straightforward enough that I wouldn't call it 'complex'. Any custom solution wouldn't be any more efficient.